# Refactoring/Vectorize a simple for loop (example data and loop included)

Tags: r

## Here is the sample code

```
# sample data
N <- 100
s <- matrix(rexp(1000000), 10000)

sif <- matrix(0,1,N)

count <- 0
# the slow for loop
for(ii in 1:(round(length(s)/N)-1)) 
{
# incdex counter for final vector
    count <- count + 1

#  populates new matrix with a range from the s matrix
sif[count,] <- s[(1+((ii-1)*N)):(ii*N)]

    # stacks new row onto matrix
sif <- rbind(sif, (count + 1))
 }
```

## Performance

With 1 million elements in a matrix, the performance is quite slow. Does anybody know how to vectorize the above sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't you just doing

```
sif <- matrix(s, ncol=N, byrow=T)
```

### Edit:

You have to be a bit careful if the count of elements of the new matrix do not match the old one exactly. Then, the following will do:

```
sif <- matrix(s[1:(round(length(s)/N)*N)], ncol=N, byrow=T)
```

I did a careful computation, calling my result `sif2`. What I got:

```
> max(abs(sif[1:9999,1:100]-sif2[1:9999,1:100]))
[1] 0
```

However,

```
> sif[10000,]
[1] 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 ...
```

Of course, as you never fill the last row of your data. Is this intended? If yes, you may easily change my result by

```
sif2[nrow(sif2), ] <- nrow(sif2)
```

There is no need to compare performace, but for the sake of completeness:

```
               User      System     elapsed 
Your way     57.831      14.056      71.525 
R's way       0.004       0.002       0.006
```

Comment: have a look at the 2nd statement in the for loop. It's placing a range of values from the s matrix.

Comment: Yes, you are taking N elements of the matrix and insert them into the new one. Then you take the next N and insert them in the next row of the matrix. That is exactly what `matrix` with `byrow=T` does.

Comment: Great work mate! I just checked out your edit. Can't believe it was that simple!